# capture and disable multitask key

Tags: android, key, capture, multitasking

My app needs to capture and then disable the multitasking key, however it does not work even I used either `KEYCODE_MENU` or `KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH`:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) { //shield Back Key
        Log.i(TAG, "shield Back Key");
        return true;
    } else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) { //shield Menu Key
        Log.i(TAG, "shield Menu Key");
        return true;
    } else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) { //this does not work
        return true;
    }else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH) { //shield Multiple Key
        Log.i(TAG, "shield Mutiple Key");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

How can we do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Android doesn't ever want to disable the home button, to prevent malware from keeping you stuck in their app and unable to leave.  There's been a few hacks that have worked on certain versions, but Google closes the loopholes as soon as it finds them.

Comment: we are talking about how to capture the multitasking key, but the home key.